# Raspberry Pi Object or specific tag sensor

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am planning to work with a Rasberry Pi in order to try and detect motion of certain things. I was thinking of capturing motion with a similar approach RFID stickers perhaps placed on objects to detect their movement. Does anyone know of a type of sensor that could recognize specific movement or what technology I may look into ?

Comment: Maybe https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=147814&p=972672&hilit=location#p972672 or look at http://www.ludions.com/projects/lichens/

Comment: There was a big thread on the R Pi forum about tracking objects recently but I can't find it for the life of me.